# ¿Cómo envío mensaje al privado de un usuario que invocó el comando !prueba en discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Quiero hacer un comando para poder mandar al privado del usuario del discord *Hola amigo bienvenido* cuando él use `!privado`.

El código que llevo (sin contar la importación del módulo y todos los requerimientos para poder usarlo) es:

```
@client.command()
async def prueba(ctx):
   await ctx.send("Bienvenido usuario aqui te envio la informacion")
```

Comment: Mmm... creo que tienes que buscar la propiedad del autor del mensaje, ya que a el le enviaras, se como hacerlo pero en js no recuerdo como era en python

Comment: Puedes leer [esto](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm)

Comment: Me podrías explica como sería por que ahi tengo que poner manualmente el id de la persona entonce necesito obtener esa id desde el bot

Comment: Más abajo te dic esto `await message.author.send('')`

Comment: Author es una propiedad de message

Comment: Entonces en mi caso seria ya que es async def privado(ctx):, el comando seria await ctx.author.send(""), nada  más eso ?

Comment: Te sugiero que veas la documentación y lastimosamente te digo esto, intenta con `ctx.message.author.send("hola")` y con lo dices, no se cual de la dos funcione perocreo que será la primera :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**La solución al problema es:**

```
@client.command()
async def prueba(ctx):
   await ctx.author.send("Bienvenido usuario aqui te envio la informacion")
```

Muchas gracias a todos los que contribuyeron